# Obtain containing object instance from ModelMetadataProvider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Implementing custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` in ASP.NET MVC2.

Assuming the object that is being rendered looks like this:

```
- Contact : IUpdateable
   - Name: string
   - ContactType: (Lead, Prospect, Customer)
```

and the method below is in the context of `Contact.ContactType` meaning that:

- `meta.PropertyName  == "ContactType"`
- `meta.ContainerType == typeof(Contact)`
- `meta.Model         == ContactType.Lead`

(the code under question:)

```
protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, 
    Type containerType,
    Func<object> modelAccessor, 
    Type modelType, string propertyName) {

    var containerInstance = meta.NotSureWhatGoesHere as IUpdateable;
    meta.IsReadOnly = containerInstance != null && containerInstance.CanBeUpdated(meta.PropertyName);
}
```

**The question**: How can I obtain the *instance* of Contact from the metadata? (replace `NotSureWhatGoesHere` with the correct one)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dirty way (tested in mvc3):

```
object target = modelAccessor.Target;
object container = target.GetType().GetField("container").GetValue(target);
```

It will return the model in
    model => model.Contact.Name 
instead of model.Contact. The rest is left as an exercise to the reader ;). This method comes, as all reflection based solutions poking around in non public data, without warranty.

Comment: That's an interesting trick! Will give it a shot later. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be more complex than that. It will be necessary to traverse an Expression tree (and compile part of it) and magically find the container based on information I have in meta. Meta does not provide any details about the container instance that can identify the needed container instance (ContainerName and type are not enough to do that as there can many of them).

Comment: For others coming along to this solution, it either doesn't work in MVC2 or it's far more complex than this.  We ended up going a different route and did not modify the Metadata Provider to gain access to the instance values.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. [I asked Brad Wilson (author of `ModelMetadata`, et. al.) about this directly, and he couldn't come up with a way.](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html#comment-6a00e54fbd8c4988340133f53f55f7970b) I eventually had to go a different route.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It sounds very disappointing. Do you know if something has changed from MVC2 to MVC3 in this regard?

Comment: @Dmytrii, I haven't looked at this in MVC 3 yet.

Comment: It does not look like this has changed in MVC3 or MVC4. The `CreateMetadata` method is still only passed the Container Type, not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what `modelAccessor` parameter is for?

Try:

```
var containerInstance = modelAccessor() as IUpdateable;
```

Comment: No, he's in the context of `ContactType.Lead`. `modelAccessor()` returns the same thing as `meta.Model` in this case; the only difference is that your code will fail if `modelAccessor` is `null`, but `meta.Model` returns null.